# EE 3.3.3 Error "Cannot modify header information"

Tags: ee3

[image]Installed EE 3.3.3 with the default theme to start learning it, and got the error.

```
Notice Undefined offset: 2

ee/legacy/database/DB_active_rec.php, line 1876 show details

Severity: E_NOTICE
Warning

Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Users/jbreen/Sites/ee-3.02-dev-site/system/ee/legacy/core/Exceptions.php:112)

ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Boot/boot.common.php, line 463 hide details
```

Its a local install with MAMP Pro.Reinstalled again same error on homepage only. Checked DB Privileges and are OK. I am Stuck.

Comment: Check for whitespace (blank lines) at the top of the mentioned PHP files, before the opening ```<?php>```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for seeing this error:

1. Some part/all of a page has been sent.
2. Cannot modify header info after a page has been sent.

Your notice is saying as much “Cannot modify header information - headers already sent”

As this is occurring only on your home page check PHP in > Template Settings & Access, Allow PHP? = No. It probably is disabled already, if it is not enabled enable it and save then disable it. Also notice “PHP Parsing Stage” in that same dialog screen, Template Settings & Access, “When set to output, PHP will be parsed after the template.”

If that does not do it, duplicate that template and troubleshoot it by removing one section at a time until the error goes.

Suspect section - slideshow.